# How would I check if a number is odd in python without using modulo or a library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, python-2.x

I am trying to determine if a number is odd or even in [python](/questions/tagged/python) without using modulus `%` or any libraries, or even bitwise calculations (`&` and `|`). I believe it has something to do with raising `n` to the power of something, but this is all I have:

```
def isOdd(num):
    return num**2 > 0
```

Which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid modulo?

Comment: And why do you now want to avoid bitwise operations?!

Comment: My guess is "because the homework says so".  Have you considered integer division?  Or is that also not allowed?

Comment: `str(num)[-1] in "13579"`?

Comment: @Teepeemm My thoughts as well. Certainly it is not true that any number with a positive square is odd!

Comment: Why would someone `+1` a question that obviously has no research :D

Comment: There are many, many possible solutions to this.  Since you've said that you can't use the most natural and obvious ones, please could you clarify the constraints a little?

Comment: @A.J. Not to mention one that's about as far as you can get from being "clear" or "useful".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can raise `-1` to the power of `n`, and see if the number is `1` or `-1`:

```
def isOdd(num):
    if type(num) not in [int, long]:
        return False
    if ((-1)**num) == 1: 
        return False 
    return True
```

As such:

```
>>> isOdd(5.2)
False
>>> isOdd(5)
True
>>> isOdd(6)
False
```

Or, you can check if the number is a float, and if it isn't see if the last digit is odd:

```
def isOdd(num):
    if type(num) not in [int, long]:
        return False
    if str(num)[-1] in "13579":
        return True
    return False
```

You can also check to see if the `num/2` is a float or an integer:

```
def isOdd(num): 
     return not (num/2.0).is_integer() and type(num) in [int, long]
```

---

```
>>> isOdd(5)
True
>>> isOdd(-3.4)
False
>>> isOdd(4)
False
```

Comment: Typechecking that way will cause problems; for example, in Python 2, your first code gives `isOdd(1000000000000000000000000001) == False`.

Comment: @DSM fixed for `long` and `int` checking

Comment: No, it's not.. to be honest, I think the typechecking is unnecessary noise here.  And if really you did care, then it's traditional to throw a TypeError rather than silently returning False, which would lead to isOdd(3.0) being False.

Comment: The first solution now gives `False` for `isOdd(5)`.  Even if you *do* do type-checking, you probably don't want to compare the *type* of `num` with the *strings* `'int'` and `'long'`. :-)

Comment: @MarkDickinson oops, my bad :D

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
def isOdd(x):
    return x - 2 * (x // 2) == 1
```

or (just kidding)

```
import math
def isOdd(x):
   return math.cos(x * math.pi) < 0
```

Comment: I cannot use bitwise calculations.

Comment: I like the `math.cos` solution, but the floating-point equality test makes me a bit nervous.  If you spell it as `math.cos(x * math.pi) < 0`, it'll give correct results for a much larger range of inputs.  (As written, it fails when `x = 25211263` on my machine, but that's just my machine: the first point of failure is going to depend on how `cos` is implemented in the system's math library.)

Comment: It's more for comic relief :)

Comment: Yes, this whole question is going the way of silly solutions.  I propose: `sum(map(int, ('1' * x).replace('11', '00'))) == 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
def isOdd(num):
    return (num & 1) == 1
```

Using the bitwise AND.

EDIT: Without bitwise in python3:

```
def isOdd(num):
    return (num / 2) != (num // 2)
```

One is true division (5/2 = 2.5) the other natural division (5/2 = 2).

Comment: This is a good and very typical solution but you should explain better. Bitwise operations are a common source of confusion for new developers.

Comment: I cannot use bitwise calculations.

Comment: The question is tagged in [tag:python-2.x].

Comment: You could convert the solution to Python 2 by doing `(num / 2.) != (num // 2)`. The // operator has been around for a good while, and the `2.` (carefully note the decimal) forces float division.

Answer (score 0):

Just another couple of ways of doing this:

```
def is_odd_1(x):
    return int(x / 2.) != x / 2.

def is_odd_2(x):
    return x // 2 != x / 2.
```

Comment: `x` would have to be constrained in size here: both these functions give `False` for an input of `10**16 + 1` (or `2**53 + 1`).